# How to fix this error in R while installing packages?

Tags: r, installation, package

This is what I did:

```
install.packages("TSA",lib="D:/R/packages")    
library(TSA,lib.loc="D:/R/packages")    
install.packages("leaps",lib="D:/R/packages")
```

still getting the error:

```
library(TSA,lib.loc="D:/R/packages") 
#Error: package ‘leaps’ required by ‘TSA’ could not be found
```

Comment: What happens when you do `library(leaps,lib.loc="D:/R/packages")` ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package TSA from CRAN. If you want to install it:

`install.packages("TSA")`

If you already have `.tar.gz` files. I suggest using Hadley Wickham's [`devtools`package](https://github.com/hadley/devtools). It allows loading package from given directory:

```
library(devtools)

# load package w/o installing
load_all('D:/R/packages')

# or invoke 'R CMD INSTALL'
install('D:/R/packages')
```